# Contextily add_basemap uses wrong extent and zoom level

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas

I'm trying to add a contextily basemap to a Matplotlib figure containing a GeoPandas data frame. When I just plot the data frame using `df.plot` the map extent is calculated correctly.

However, when I try adding a contextily basemap the map extent (and zoom level) is calculated wrongly and the following warning is shown:

```
UserWarning: The inferred zoom level of 27 is not valid for the current tile provider (valid zooms: 0 - 20).
```

I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
df = gpd.read_file('linz/StatBez_Linz_EPSG_4326.gml')
df = df.to_crs(epsg=3857)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
ax = plt.subplot()
ctx.add_basemap(ax = ax, source=ctx.providers.Stamen.Toner, crs=df.crs.to_string())
df.plot(color='none',edgecolor='green', ax = ax)
```

The output of `df.tail()` can be seen here:

[image]

The `gml` file is from [data.gv.at](https://www.data.gv.at/katalog/dataset/stadt-linz_statistischebezirkelinzbis20131231/resource/67a223f5-1dd2-41c7-b92c-c6bb58f67ef3)

Comment: are you sure your code is correct? the second line should not work because you haven't defined `linz_districts`. Despite, what does the first `df`'s crs (try identifying the crs of the first df before doing the projection)? Have you manually adjust the contextily `zoom` parameter to 20?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @sutan, I edited the code above. I changed all the variable names before copying the code into the question. The values that come out of the crs projection are as expected.

Except for the code above, nothing was set up in contextily, therefore also the zoom level wasn't manually set

Comment: First plot GeoDataFrame, then add a basemap.

Comment: That solves it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment above, the GeoDataFrame needs to be plotted on the axis first before adding the basemap with contextily.

```py
df = gpd.read_file('linz/StatBez_Linz_EPSG_4326.gml')
df = df.to_crs(epsg=3857)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
ax = plt.subplot()
df.plot(color='none',edgecolor='green', ax = ax)
ctx.add_basemap(ax = ax, source=ctx.providers.Stamen.Toner)
```